# Unresolved reference to DaggerApplicationComponent

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger, kapt

I can't handle error related to Dagger and it's generation of component.

```
import android.app.Application
import dagger.Component

@Component(modules = arrayOf(ApplicationModule::class))
interface ApplicationComponent{
    fun inject(app: Application)
}
```

The place where component is called looks like that

```
class MyAwesomeApplication : Application(){
    val component: ApplicationComponent by lazy {
        DaggerApplicationComponent.builder().appModule(ApplicationModule(this)).build()
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        component.inject(this)
    }
}
```

In gradle build file I have set up:

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$dagger_version"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$dagger_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$dagger_version"
```

Also the stub generation is turned on and `kotlin-kapt` has been applied

Any ideas what is wrong there?

Comment: After some time looks that the problem was with kapt dependency I have been using "dagger-android-processor" where I should use dagger-compiller.

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle file as well.

Comment: There is nothing there besides standard stuff additional dependencies and stub generation for kotlin-kapt and as I have mentioned the missing one was dagger-compiller dependency.

Comment: @Robert Thank you for posting your answer! Rather than the comments, please consider [adding it below as a "self-answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and marking it accepted--it helps potential answerers know that you've solved your problem, and lets you get credit in the future when someone else stumbles on a similar problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Your `build.gradle` should look something like this

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
…
dependencies {
…
    final dagger_version = '2.17'
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"
    compileOnly 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'
}
```

I think what you are missing is `compileOnly 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'`. I have an [article for detailed steps to setup Dagger](https://medium.com/@xiwei/simplest-dagger-example-920bbd10258).

Answer (score 0):

app.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
kapt {
  generateStubs = true
}
}

// Dagger 2
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger2_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger2_version"
```

Build -> Rebuild project

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a gradle dependency issue. Solved it by adding the following to the app.gradle script:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
.
.
dependencies {
    .
    .
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger2_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$dagger2_version"
}
```

Then I cleaned and rebuilt the project.

Answer (score 0):

```
For me its because of dagger version. By using the below version resolved the issue for me.

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

dagger_version = '2.17'
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"
```